# CWM bypass md5 checking

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

Is there a way to bypass the md5 checking before restore in CWM?

This is **not** an issue with an md5 mismatch (the solution to which can be easily found via google/search)

The idea is that I am performing many restores (currently tinkering with some of the inner workings) and am not too concerned that the recovery has been altered/corrupted since it's probably been not too long since I last reflashed) and checking the md5sum takes up a fair amount of overhead (2x the read operations).

It's not a huge deal but if anyone knows a solution please let me know!

Comment: No, the MD5 checksum is actually built into the CWM to verify the check on the backup nandroid image, its there for that reason.

Comment: I had this same issue and I found that Philz touch recovery is a fork of CWM but has the option to disable verification. I'm happy with it. :) May be you can find one for your device.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, if you can i would highly recommend just using TWRP it has alot more features and allow you to skip all the md5 stuff. plus it has a built in file manager for swapping out systemUI.apk ext.

AND it has a command mode to allow for more advanced scripting and modding.

Comment: Using an alternative isn't a bad thing but would you care to explain how the CWM backups can be ported to TWRP and restored from it. That would be both helpful and complete as an answer. (Avoid posting links only).

Comment: @Firelord hard but impossible as they use different encryption ext. Just restore your stuff in cwm. and then use TWRP from then on. And if you are pronoid just backup up with TWRP right after you restored form CWM therefor you know it 99.99% legit data. Then keep the cwm around just incase. You could always go back to using CWM , restore then come back to TWRP.